# SensioGeneratorBundle - apply changes in Entity-generator.yml to crud

Tags: symfony, crud

I successfully generated a CRUD screen with php app/console generate:doctrine:crud

Now, when I change settings in my yml file: Entity-generator.yml, for example the columns to display in a list, how do I apply these changes to the screens?

In Symfony1 a simple cache-clear was enough.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with :

```
app/console cache:clear --env=dev  ( or prod for app.php )
```

And then refreshing the page ?
That should do it.

If not, make sure that you don't need to run the whole CRUD again to generate the new columns, after reading [the docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/commands/generate_doctrine_crud.html) it sounds like it may be the way to go.